# Why document.getElementById isn't recognize only by Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have the following code, which simply generating the random
sequence from a list.
It works fine in Chrome and Safari:

```js
var strings = [
  'For he who can wait, everything comes in time.',
    'We will wait to see if it is a doozy before we decide how to cover it, and what it all means.',
    'We need to talk about what we are going to do and see and decide. We\'ll have to wait and see.'
];

var rand = strings[Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length)];
document.getElementById('loading-text').innerText = rand;
```

```css
.loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.loading-gif {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #aaa;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class='loading' >
     <div id='loading-text' class='loading-text'></div>
     <img class="loading-gif" id="processing" src= "images/squares.gif"/>
</div>
```

But when I run it in Firefox the JavaScript didn't work (e.g. the random string isn't generated). How can I enable that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed the problem.

Firefox does not support [the non-standard innerText property](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/).

Use `textContent` instead.

```js
var strings = [
  'For he who can wait, everything comes in time.',
    'We will wait to see if it is a doozy before we decide how to cover it, and what it all means.',
    'We need to talk about what we are going to do and see and decide. We\'ll have to wait and see.'
];

var rand = strings[Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length)];
document.getElementById('loading-text').textContent = rand;
```

```css
.loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.loading-gif {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #aaa;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class='loading' >
     <div id='loading-text' class='loading-text'></div>
     <img class="loading-gif" id="processing" src= "images/squares.gif"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you could also use innerHTML property,

```js
var strings = [
  'For he who can wait, everything comes in time.',
    'We will wait to see if it is a doozy before we decide how to cover it, and what it all means.',
    'We need to talk about what we are going to do and see and decide. We\'ll have to wait and see.'
];

var rand = strings[Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length)];
document.getElementById('loading-text').innerHTML = rand;
```

```css
.loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.loading-gif {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #aaa;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class='loading' >
     <div id='loading-text' class='loading-text'></div>
     <img class="loading-gif" id="processing" src= "images/squares.gif"/>
</div>
```